# C++ class in Python via Ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
public:
    void bar(){
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
extern "C" {
Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }  # I tried __declspec(dllexport) on these funcs, same error
void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

I compiled this into a MODULE library and tried to access this class in Python:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('C:\\Users\\avishah\\CLionProjects\\Math\\lib\\libpythonclass.dll')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)
```

The problem is that it fails to load the library itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/avishah/PycharmProjects/Math/pythoncpp/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL('C:\\Users\\avishah\\CLionProjects\\Math\\lib\\libpythonclass.dll')
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\avishah\CLionProjects\Math\lib\libpythonclass.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I tried many examples online but all fail with this error... One thing I noticed is the other examples all had .so files but since I'm on Windows, I use .dll files, also there is an additional need for __declspec(dllexport).

**EDIT:**
I am using MinGW compiler. Is this related to the compiler? Should I be using MSVC compiler?

Comment: Search for the error message online, this is not really an uncommon problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I did... I couldn't find much though, some suggested using os.abspath, or adding dll directory via os, none of which work for me.

Comment: Use the dependency walker or a similar tool to determine dependencies of `libpythonclass.dll`.

Comment: Alternatively to dependency walker open command prompt for VS, and run `dumpbin /dependents libpythonclass.dll`.

Comment: I tried the dependency walker, and it shows me a ton of 'Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)' and at the bottom it says 'Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.'
These are the dependencies using VS cmd: KERNEL32.dll, msvcrt.dll, libstdc++-6.dll

Comment: KERNEL32.dll is ok, Windows knows where to find it, but msvcrt.dll and libstdc++-6.dll are not.  You need to either eliminate those by using static linking, or place them somewhere Windows can find them (in the path, or next to your dll). There is lots of info out there.